# Chamilo_Post_max_size not changed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, upload, xampp

I'm using chamilo for training portal, and wat to chage limit of quota upload for user, already tried set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf, user.ini but no luck. this what I do

php.ini and user.ini

```
max_input_vars = 200
file_upload = on
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 201M
```

.htaccess and httpd.conf

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 20800
php_value max_input_time       20800
php_value max_execution_time     20800
php_value upload_max_filesize    200MB
php_value post_max_size        201MB
```

please help me out, I'm using php 5